# How can we tell, from the SDE, that a GBM can never take the value of 0 or infinity (for $t > 0$)?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

The lecture notes on stochastic processes that I am currently reading state that

> The SDE given by $$dX_t = \mu X_t dt + \sigma X_t dW_t$$ (for known constants $\mu$ and $\sigma > 0$) is known as a geometric Brownian motion (GBM). **The rate of change of $X_t$ is proportional to $X_t$ meaning that GBM never hits zero (or infinity by time inversion).**

Could someone clarify for me what this means?

Answer (score 0):

From Ito's lemma it follows that this GBM SDE has the following solution (see e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion)

$$X_t=X_0exp((\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t+\sigma W_t)$$

Now $X_t=0$ requires $W_t=-\infty$ and $X_t=\infty$ requires $W_t=\infty$. But the Wiener process takes values only on the reals $\mathbb{R}$. This follows from the normally distributed increments property of the Wiener process and the fact that the normal distribution is defined on the reals. Infinity is not a real number.